# Out of Space, Out of Space, Out of Space, Out of Space,

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

Can someone tell me, succinctly, how to prevent this very irritating problem happening ever again?  According to someone's advice to another poster (possibly from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9387415)), I ran this command:

```
sudo find . -xdev -type f | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

and got the following message:

```
sort: write failed: /tmp/sort7tteF8: No space left on device
```

---

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           800M  1.9M  798M   1% /run
/dev/sdb5        17G   16G   16M 100% /
tmpfs           4.0G   61M  3.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1      4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/352
/dev/loop3      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
/dev/loop2       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/206
/dev/loop4       35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
/dev/loop7      152M  152M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/31
/dev/loop10     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78
/dev/loop13      91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6405
/dev/loop16     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/loop11     7.5M  7.5M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/69
/dev/loop15     1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/57
/dev/loop18     203M  203M     0 100% /snap/vlc/770
/dev/loop12      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop5       36M   36M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/loop0       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/254
/dev/loop17     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/77
/dev/loop14     1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop8       54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/941
/dev/loop6      4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop19     2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/loop20     203M  203M     0 100% /snap/vlc/768
/dev/loop24     144M  144M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/23
/dev/loop23      90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/loop30      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/782
/dev/loop21     7.5M  7.5M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/58
/dev/loop27     196M  196M     0 100% /snap/vlc/555
/dev/loop26      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
/dev/loop22     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/70
/dev/loop29     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
/dev/loop28      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/6531
/dev/loop25      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
/dev/sda1       188M  5.8M  182M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           800M   52K  800M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda4       699G   28G  671G   4% /media/joe/Storage
/dev/sdb1       915G  829G   87G  91% /media/joe/C040B0ED40B0EB74
/dev/loop31     7.5M  7.5M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/74
/dev/loop32     152M  152M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/36
```

---

Archived and active journals take up 800.3M in the file system.

Comment: Take a screenshot of Gparted and upload it in imgur.com and add the link in your answer. We need more information about your system and partitions.

Comment: Are you still running the smallish root partition shown in [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080358/how-to-delete-alongside-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080358/how-to-delete-alongside-ubuntu)?

Comment: "Somebody help me, please! Thank you." Why? You don't want to hear about inodes, long lists of commands, scrolling. Well guess what we all went through these kind of things and most of us did not even have askubuntu or even a bleeding internet. Want out help? Ranting aint the correct method.

Comment: Joe, first please dont rant in the question, the last paragraph is essentially pointless. Second, you may want to check /var/log directory because 9/10 times there is an error overfilling logs. Consider also temporarily attaching USB and moving files or getting rid of packages to clear out some disk space. Error comes out because some commands use temp files to run correctly

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include the output of `df -h` and `sudo sudo journalctl --disk-usage`?

Answer (score 0):

to make some space run **(sudo) apt-get autoclean** and cap the journal with **(sudo) journalctl --vacuum-files=2**, **(sudo) journalctl --vacuum-size=64M**. on the journal run both versions with and without sudo to cap for root and user.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake by trying to partition my HDD for a **dual-boot** system.  I will try to fix this mess once and for all by re-installing Ubuntu as a **single-boot** system.